# How to search tweets in replies and retweets?

Tags: php, twitter

I want to make an app almost the same as dell canada. http://www.facebook.com/DellCanada?v=app_137102584517&ref=nf .

On the right side, "twitter sphere". it is able to be filtered by a keyword from Replies and Retweets. I have googled for a long time, still didn't get any idea how to do it.

And thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Bill

Answer (score 2):

They're just using the [Twitter Search API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method:-search).